# Why does not gif display work with StdDraw while png work?

Tags: java, gif, stddraw

I am currently coding a small game, and i have (i think) a very simple bug, but i didn't found the solution anywhere.
Here is my problem : when I wants to display a .png image, i have no problem, but it absolutelly don't work at all, saying me that "the image folder does not exist" but it does !

```
StdDraw.picture(this.position.getX(), this.position.getY(), "ressources/sunflower.png");
```

This works perfectilly but when i try with the .gif version (which exist of course), nope (i really wants to use StdDraw).